# Concatenate two node values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML structure, and I need to combine the values of `handlingInstructionText`:

```
<handlingInstruction>
    <handlingInstructionText>CTAC  |  MARTINE HOEYLAERTS</handlingInstructionText>
</handlingInstruction>
<handlingInstruction>
    <handlingInstructionText>PHON  |  02/7225235</handlingInstructionText>
</handlingInstruction>
```

My expected output is

```
CTAC  |  MARTINE HOEYLAERTS PHON  |  02/7225235
```

I'm currently using the string-join function but it seems not supported by the version of xsl that I'm currently using.

```
<xsl:value-of select="otxsl:var-put('Join2_handlingInstructionText',
string-join(handlingInstruction/concat(handlingInstructionText/text(),
' ', handlingInstructionText/text())))" />
```

I already tried using a `for-each` function to get each value but I want it to make it a 1 line code only.

Comment: Please do not post snippets out of their context - it makes it difficult for us to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(handlingInstruction[1]/handlingInstructionText,
                             ' ',
                             handlingInstruction[2]/handlingInstructionText)"/>
```

will return your expected output:

```
CTAC | MARTINE HOEYLAERTS PHON | 02/7225235
```

for your given input XML:

```
<r>
  <handlingInstruction>
      <handlingInstructionText>CTAC  |  MARTINE HOEYLAERTS</handlingInstructionText>
  </handlingInstruction>
  <handlingInstruction>
      <handlingInstructionText>PHON  |  02/7225235</handlingInstructionText>
  </handlingInstruction>
</r>
```

assuming `r` is the current node.   **[<kbd>Click to try</kbd>](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpK)**

---

Update: So, in the context of your `var-put` extension, this would be:

```
<xsl:value-of select=
              "otxsl:var-put('Join2_handlingInstructionText',
                              concat(handlingInstruction[1]/handlingInstructionText,
                                     ' ',
                                     handlingInstruction[2]/handlingInstructionText))"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I already tried using a for-each function to get each value but I want
>   it to make it a 1 line code only.

You should make it as many lines as it takes. As it happens, you could use:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="handlingInstruction/handlingInstructionText"/>
```

to produce the desired result, but:

```
<xsl:for-each select="handlingInstruction">
    <xsl:value-of select="handlingInstructionText"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

is perfectly fine, too.

---

**Note**: Both of the above suggestions assume a well-formed input such as:

```
<root>
    <handlingInstruction>
        <handlingInstructionText>CTAC  |  MARTINE HOEYLAERTS</handlingInstructionText>
    </handlingInstruction>
    <handlingInstruction>
        <handlingInstructionText>PHON  |  02/7225235</handlingInstructionText>
    </handlingInstruction>
</root>
```

and a a template matching `root`.

Comment: I like this solution for its elegance, but I'd be concerned about the robustness of relying on insignificant whitespace between elements to achieve the space OP wants between the string values of the two `handlingInstructionText` elements.

Comment: @kjhughes Insignificant whitespace between elements can be stripped. However, I believe it plays no role here, because the templates are applied narrowly.

Comment: Actually, that's right -- this won't add space between the two `handlingInstructionText` values without further adjustment.