# Show the separator once only the 2nd value exist

Tags: xslt

```
<handlingInstruction>
    <handlingInstructionText>CTAC  |  MARTINE HOEYLAERTS</handlingInstructionText>
</handlingInstruction>
<handlingInstruction>
    <handlingInstructionText>PHON  |  02/7225235</handlingInstructionText>
</handlingInstruction>
```

I have The above given xml structure I concatenate them and use a comma as a separator using below code

```
> <xsl:value-of
> select="concat(handlingInstruction[1]/handlingInstructionText,
>                              ',',
>                              handlingInstruction[2]/handlingInstructionText)"/>
```

I would like to ask how will I make the comma separator appear only once the 2nd exist the shortest way possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: Will there always be 1 or 2 handlingInstruction nodes?  Could there be 3 or more, and will you have to deal with all of them if so, or just the first 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `xsl:for-each`, try:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="handlingInstruction/handlingInstructionText"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="handlingInstructionText">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

*(continued from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34679465/3016153)*

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:for-each select="handlingInstruction">
    <xsl:value-of select="handlingInstructionText"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This will iterate over all handlingInstruction elements and output the value of the handlingInstructionText element.  It will add to the end of each element, if it is not the last one (which the first one would be if there was only one), a comma.

In your example, you only used two handlingInstruction elements.  If you want to only use two with this method, do

```
<xsl:for-each select="handlingInstruction[position()&lt;3]">
    <xsl:value-of select="handlingInstructionText"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note the `&lt;` there.  That is actually a less than sign (<), but we can't use that in xml so we use the entity defined for it.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response but I'm trying to avoid the use of for-each

Comment: I added a second approach which avoids the for-each using xslt2 as an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second way to do it, which avoids the for-each loop.

If you are using xslt version 2, there is a string-join function which could be used like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(//handlingInstruction/handlingInstructionText,',')"/>
```

The string-join method takes a sequence of strings (which the nodes selected will be converted to by taking their content) and concatenates them with the separator.  If there is only one string, a separator will not be added.

Alternatively, xslt 2 also provides a separator attribute on the value-of element.  Thus

```
<xsl:value-of select="//handlingInstruction/handlingInstructionText" separator=","/>
```

produces the same result.

Comment: I am adding a second answer here as it is a distinct method from the first answer which is a valid legitimate approach to the problem.  [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/is-it-ok-to-post-multiple-answers-to-a-question) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) suggest that it is best to have these as two separate answers.

Comment: Thanks again string-join Is actually one of the functions I saw on the net that fits but sadly this function is not supported by the xsl version I have.

Comment: If you can't use xlst 2, I think the for-each loop (or an equivalent) approach is the only possibility.  Most of the features added to xslt2 were to address things that were overly complicated in xslt 1, like this problem.